# Updating MySQL data table with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm working on a simple project for a client, but I cannot get past editing and updating data in mysql. Here's my code that is passed from the edit submission form:

updateinfo.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $id = $row['id'];
  $fname = $row['firstName'];

$sql = "UPDATE  `db`.`client_information` SET  `firstName` =  '$fname' WHERE  `client_information`.`id` = '$id'";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "Updated!";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

clientedit.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysql_connect_error();
}
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `client_information` WHERE id='$id'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $id = $row['id'];
  $fname = $row['firstName'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<form role="form" action="updateinfo.php" method="post">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <fieldset disabled>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" class="form-control" id="id">
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" class="form-control" id="fname">
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

**Update**
After changing the variables, when I pass the information through the form (clientedit.php), updateinfo.php updates the table with new information. However, it only works if I say: "SELECT * FROM `client_information` WHERE `id` ='31'. If I change it to say: "SELECT * FROM `client_information` WHERE `id` ='$id'", then it fails completely. I know I'm not "dynamically" connecting the ids across files.

Comment: You need to loop through your initial query in order to get the rows.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? You'll need to be more specific. Are there any errors? Is it just not updating?

Comment: Added a bit more to my question. @Arif_suhail_123 I'm not sure if anything is passing through the form.

Comment: @Nathan I'm not sure if anything is passing through or how to check. Help? :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I looped through in the form.

Comment: @joshlsullivan So, does Arif's answer work for you? If it doesn't, let the person why and if you're getting any error messages. If you're not checking for errors, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, plus `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`. You also need to change `mysql_connect_error()` to `mysqli_connect_error()` in `clientedit.php` - You're mixing MySQL APIs, they do not mix. That could be part of the problem.

Comment: I just got this message: Notice: Undefined index: firstName in /var/www/html/updateinfo.php on line 10

Comment: @joshlsullivan I posted something below you can give a try, it works. Whether it's what you're looking for, am unsure but give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

**Scroll down and start reading where it say new answer.**
if your php code is in the same page you need to change the form action like this

if not leave it like the way you have it.

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
```

you need to give name to both of your input like this

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
```

and you are using post method in the form so your $id should be like this

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

do the same for second feild like this

```
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
```

**New Answer**

The only thing we missed yesterday. is that you are using disable fieldset. for input feild. remove this. Your query code and query should work. See the code below. and dont forget to change the connnection info as my one is different from yours.

As i am assuming that you dont want user to change their id. Just use hidden attribute in input. not disable

**update one**

```
<?php
//you may have to change the value in connection variable. 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];



$sql = "UPDATE  `db`.`client_information` SET  `firstName` =  '$fname' WHERE  `client_information`.`id` = '$id'";
mysqli_query($con, $sql) or  mysqli_error($con);
echo "Updated!";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**cleint one**

```
<?php
//again you might have to change connection value in the below line
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysql_connect_error();
}
$id=$_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `client_information` WHERE id='$id'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $id = $row['id'];
  $fname = $row['firstName'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<form role="form" action="updateinfo.php" method="post">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <fieldset >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id;?>" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

Comment: $_GET['id'] seems to pick id from former form.

Comment: Well, clientedit.php seems to be the file which leeds to updateinfo.php (according to the form action). As he selects where id='$id' in clientedit.php, it must be from a former form or get transmission.

Comment: So I changed everything, but instead of updating in the database, it just erases the field completely. I'm so confused.

Comment: Ah ha... I got this message after adding error reporting: "Notice: Undefined index: firstName in /var/www/html/updateinfo.php on line 10. At the moment, I'm picking an id to manipulate, but later want to add it to an "edit" form dynamically.

Comment: If you are getting $id value in client.php you dont have to change any thing. You just have to change the form as i mentioned. in the solution. Second you are getting undefined inedex frstname; i will tell you letter why you are getting this. after changing the input feild in forum. tell what you are trying to do through form. means when every some one submit the form. You want to run the update query in `updateinfo.php` if this is what you want to do. let me know. I will tell you about your error as well. remember nothing need to change in client.php from your original code. Only input feild

Comment: limit was finish in last comment. let me know if you are confused english is not my first language.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I can completely understand you. After changing all the variables to reflect the columns in the table, it started working correctly. However, I'm still getting: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/updateinfo.php on line 8.

Comment: ok tell me what you got in that line. means on line just copy and paste to me in the comment. I will have a look

Comment: If I change the "WHERE" to '31' (id in database), it works, but I get an error. If I change it to "$sql = "UPDATE `client_information` SET firstName = '$firstName' WHERE  `client_information`.`id` = '$id'";", then it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Once the submission is passed through the form (to updateinfo.php), then it can update if ids match from file. However, it can dynamically edit the database.

Comment: where to 31, it work. and work through form as well. as you can enter 31 in id column their. And i also asked you if you click on submit, do you get that undefined index error or not. Thanks

Comment: No error on the form, but once I hit submit, I get Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/updateinfo.php on line 8

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I updated my question with more info. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the code to this: 

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

Then I added name="submit" to the form button. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, see if this is what you're looking for, it works. I couldn't get yours to work for some reason.

It will first query your database then you can edit which one you like right away.

**N.B.:** It is only to UPDATE existing data and not to add or delete.

I modified an existing script I found on the web which had a few missing parts to make it work.

These columns have been used for the following:

- id
- firstName
- lastName
- email

**HTML/PHP/SQL** (update.php)

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM `your_table`";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center">
<?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['firstName']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastName']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>">
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

// these variables were missing from the tutorial. Not having those made entries blank when doing the UPDATE.
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];

$sql1="UPDATE `your_table` SET firstName='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, stripslashes($name[$i]))."', lastName='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, stripslashes($lastname[$i]))."', email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, stripslashes($email[$i]))."' WHERE id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, stripslashes($id[$i]))."'";

// Old unsecure method. Do not use mysqli_real_escape_string and/or stripslashes as predefined variables, it won't work
// $sql1="UPDATE `your_table` SET firstName='$name[$i]', lastName='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
   }
}

if($result1){
    header("location: update.php");
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```